# action [clustering/cluster] is unauthorized for user [elastic]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

Elasticsearch has three nodes in my cluster, I am using plugin elasticsearch-carrot2, and `elastic` is a superuser in elasticsearch.

The requests I sent is below:

```
curl -XPOST --user elastic:****  -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    'http://ip:port/index/type/_search_with_clusters?pretty=true' -d '
 {
    "search_request": {
        "_source" : [
            "title",
            "body"
                   ],
        "query" : {
        "match" : {
          "title" : "something"
        }
    },
    "size": 100
          },
     "query_hint": "something",
       "field_mapping": {
          "title"  : ["_source.title", "_source.body"]
       }
 }'
```

Unfortunately I get following error:

```
{
    "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
            {
                "type" : "security_exception",
                "reason" : "action [clustering/cluster] is unauthorized 
                            for user [elastic]"
            }
                       ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "action [clustering/cluster] is unauthorized for user 
                [elastic]"
               },
    "status" : 403
}
```

Comment: Which version of ES and the plugin are you running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the plugin doesn't work with XPack security.

More info can be seen in this issue: https://github.com/carrot2/elasticsearch-carrot2/issues/69